# What disadvantages of using jsonb_array_elements for batching?

Tags: java, postgresql

I did some experiments with the performance of my `RabbitMQ listener` which has to insert a batch to `PostgreSQL`.

I got a significant improvement in the performance when used `jsonb_array_elements`.

For example:

**Table students**

```sql
CREATE TABLE students
(
    id            BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name          VARCHAR(64)  NOT NULL,
    age           INT          NOT NULL,
    average_score NUMERIC(2)   NOT NULL
)
```

**Insert SQL**

```sql
INSERT INTO students (name, age, average_score)
SELECT arg ->> 0, (arg -> 1)::INT, (arg -> 2)::INT
FROM jsonb_array_elements(?) AS arg
```

And then execute the query by `JdbcTemplate`:

```java
var sql = "<SQL>";
var args = generate(10000); // List<Object[]>
var pGobject = new PGobject();
pGobject.setType("jsonb");
pGobject.setValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(args));
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, pGobject);
```

Time difference between this approach and the traditional batch is **50%** (10000 rows locally) like this:

```java
var sql = "INSERT INTO students (id, name, age, average_score) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?)";
var args = generate(COUNT);  // List<Object[]>
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, args, new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.INTEGER, Types.NUMERIC});
```

I see only pluses to use `jsonb_array_elements` (of course `SQL` can be a little bit strange), but in common this way attracts me, I even can use `INSERT...RETURNING` to return generated `ids`.

Could somebody show me the disadvantages of this approach until I used it in my projects widely? Maybe there are some possible pitfalls?